# Display random number in slide using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to generate a random number between 1 and 30 and display it on every slide. I found the following code online:

```vb
Sub UpdateRandomNumber(oSh As Shape)
    Dim X As Long
    'Make the shape’s text a random number
    'X or less
    'Change 12 below to any number you’d like:
    X = 30
 
    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(Random(X))
End Sub
 
Function Random(High As Long) As Long
    'Generates a random number less than or equal to
    'the value passed in High
    Randomize
    Random = Int((High * Rnd) + 1)
End Function

Sub RandomNumber()

End Sub
```

I need the code to do one thing differently:
The object prompting the action is in the same spot on all slides. When generating and displaying a random number, all slides should be changed accordingly.
When I leave the slide, the previously generated number should be shown instead of the one that was previously generated on this slide.

Comment: What distinguishes the shape that contains the number on each slide? Do they all have the same name, or same position, or something else?

Comment: @JohnKorchok They all share the same name and position, since I've copied and pasted them from one slide to all the other slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a random number between 1 and 30. Change the shape name to the actual shape used in your file:

```
Sub ShapeNumber()
    Dim X As Long
    Dim ShapeNumber As String
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape

    X = 30
    Randomize
    ShapeNumber = Int((X * Rnd) + 1)
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.Name = "Rectangle 3" Then
                oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ShapeNumber
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```